# How to concat large amount of files conveniently?

Tags: python, concatenation

I want to concat 365 files into 1 dataframe. All the files have the same column names, with the first column stating the date and time. I imagine there is another way to concat these files without having to type the 365 file names seperately in Python?

Comment: If they're in a directory, you could loop over all files in the directory. Similarly, do a file tree walk and get all files with the proper <regex> name or extension

Comment: "without having to type the 365 file names seperately" – Is your goal to concatenate these files efficiently, or is your goal to not type the 365 file names? Are they all in the same folder? Are there other files in the folder? Are you aware of the various folder/file listing tools, such as ``glob``, ``os.walk``, ``os.listdir`` and such? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are indeed some other files in the folder. Should I make a new folder with only the files I need? I'm not aware of the listing tools you mentioned. I didn't try anything yet as the only method I found involves typing all the files seperately, which will not only take a while but also clutter the code.

Comment: You should clearly define what you are trying to achieve. That includes whether you are willing and able (as in, is it feasible?) to separate the wanted files into another folder.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It will be easy to put the files in a new folder. What I am trying to achieve is to combine these files into one dataframe, as in this picture: https://gyazo.com/337d57ddbe570e0bb70b4597a32b4306